# Issue with CORS while trying POST request

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cors, http-post

I am trying to send a post request from my angularJS application which is running on 4200 port as follows to the nodeJS application running on different port 3000.

AngularJS 2.0 Code:

```
addNewItem(body:string) {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://10.244.1.59:3000/newBinDevice',body,{
      headers: headers
    })
    .map((response : Response) => response.json());
  }
```

NodeJS code

```
var express = require('express');

    module.exports = function(app){
        var db = require('./dbclient');
        var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
        app.use(bodyParser.json());
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
        db.dbconnection(null,null,null,null,'smartbin',null);
        app.post('/newItem', function(req, res, next) { 
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            //res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"); 
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type"); 
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
            console.log('body request is ' +  req.body + " after stringifying it " + JSON.stringify(req.body) + " array to string " + req.body.toString());
    }
```

I am getting CORS issue saying that `" Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404."` I read somewhere that one cannot send data other than

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded
multipart/form-data
text/plain
```

When I tried to send data as a string instead of JSON object from AngularJS application, i am getting empty data on nodejs application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add some more middleware to your express application to support [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

You can use the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package:

```
var cors = require('cors')
...
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

That will enable the package's default CORS configuration. The configuration options are outlined in detail in the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#usage).

The problem with the code in your question is that you are including the CORS headers in the `POST` response, but they need to be returned in the pre-flight `OPTIONS` response. Rather than coding your own CORS implementation, I would suggest using the package mentioned above.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I made small changes in my above code as follows. var cors = require('cors');
 var coptions = {
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,POST,OPTIONS",
  "preflightContinue": true
 };  app.post('/newBinDevice', cors(coptions), function(req, res, next) {console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));} Though the server is getting the post request, the post parameter value is being received as an empty json object. Not able to figure out what is the problem here.

Comment: Don't use `preflightContinue`. The browser will be sending two requests: the first using the `OPTIONS` method; and the second using the `POST` method. The `OPTIONS` request is the pre-flight request; you don't want to handle that in your `post` route. Let the `cors` module handle the `OPTIONS` request/response. You don't see the body because it's not passed in the `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: I removed preFlightContinue totally and also tested setting it to false. In both cases, i am still receiving empty JSON object. when i looked at request payload on my browser, i am able to see the JSON object in request payload. But on the server side i am receiving empty object.

Comment: If the request is arriving at your `post` route, the CORS issue is solved. Whether or not the body arrives as you're expecting it has nothing to do with CORS. With CORS, the request is allowed or it isn't. Your CORS issue is solved and rather than updating/extending your question to address your body problem, I think a new asking a new, body-related question would be the preferred option.

Comment: CORS issue is solved as well as request body issue too. Its a minor logical issue in my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i am new in stackoverflow, but faced this problem before some time:

use this code in your app.

```
var cors = require('cors');


app.use(cors({
    'allowedHeaders': ['sessionId', 'Content-Type'],
    'exposedHeaders': ['sessionId'],
    'origin': '*',
    'methods': 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    'preflightContinue': false

}));
```

And make sure that disable your CORS extension in your browser if any.